# Feature specs on https pages with capybara + poltergeist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I've been trying to create a feature spec with "js: true" for a https page.

I'm using Rails4.2 + rspec + capybara + poltergeist.

I can test http pages with capybara + poltergeist without any problem. However, I can't find a way to test https pages with capybara + poltergeist.

Can anyone guide me on how to accomplish this?

spec/rails_helper.rb

```
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(
    app,
    phantomjs_options: [
      '--debug=no',
      '--load-images=no',
      '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes',
      '--ssl-protocol=TLSv1'
    ],
    debug: false
  )
end
```

https_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.feature 'https' do
  let(:admin) { create(:admin) }

  scenario 'display admin dashboard', js: true do
    login_as(admin, scope: :user)
    visit admin_dashboard_index_path
    expect(page).to have_text('TEST')
  end
end
```

I get this message

```
Failures:

  1) https display admin dashboard
     Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
     RuntimeError:
       tried to create a new session when on http, but https is required
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is the solution to your problem:

http://cowjumpedoverthecommodore64.blogspot.com/2013/09/if-your-website-runs-under-ssl-than.html